# How to translate this Shader function to JS?

Tags: javascript, shader

So I found this very useful peace of code in Shader `vec2 cmp = step(t_max.xy, t_max.yx);`. I need to translate it to JavaScript. But no idea how.

`Vec2` I simply assume as 2d array, where index 0 is x and 1 is y.

```
var cmp = step([t_max[0], t_max[1]], [t_max[1], t_max[0]]);
```

But the step part hard for me. Even after checking https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml

Comment: Why is it hard for you? What specifically are you struggling to achieve?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just updated the question. I just don't understand the `step` function to recreate it in JavaScript.

Comment: What are `genType`s?

Comment: It is strange that you call it useful but you don't know what it does. This is my understanding of it: Given two arrays - `A` and `B` - of equal length, return an array where each element represents `B[i] >= A[i] ? 1 : 0`. Should be incredibly straightforward to rewrite in most languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`step`, as defined in GLSL, simply takes two parameters: `edge` and `x` (or `input`). It returns 0.0 when `x < edge` and 1.0 when the opposite is true. To use it with a `vec2` (an array of size 2 - not 2d array) you can define a function like this:

```
function step(edge, input) {
    x = edge[0] > input[0] ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    y = edge[1] > input[1] ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    return [x, y]
}
```

Comment: Why `0.0` specifically? `0.0 === 0 // true`

Comment: In GLSL setting a value as `0` isn't the same as `0.0`, as you must specifically set a variable as int or float (if a functions requires a `float` and you give it `0` you get an error).  In JS, here, I suppose it doesn't matter, I just wanted to stick with the spirit of the shader code.

Comment: P.S you should not use `x` (screwing up input for second test) and undefined y. But the concept is right.

Comment: Yeah, JavaScript only has one number type (except “BigInt”). I thought I’d mention it as people get confused enough between Java and Javascript

Comment: `function step(edge, x) {
    var a = edge[0] > x[0] ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    var b = edge[1] > x[1] ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    return [a, b]
}` this works